# How can i fix donation error: This item is not currently for sale. Your account has not been charged. [ROBLOX]

Tags: lua, roblox

Code:

```
game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptPurchase(script.Parent.Parent, 1083008134)
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could simply be that your product hasn't been configured properly. Looking at the [documentation for Developer Products](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Game-Passes-One-Time-Purchases#configure-the-pass), have you marked the product as "For Sale"?

> 3. Click the Item for Sale toggle switch to make the pass available to players.
>    [image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current way to do it is

```
game:GetService(“MarketplaceService”):PromptGamePassPurchase(player, productId)
```